# In Excel, provided the column number, find the empty next empty cell and enter a data. (Java)

Tags: java, excel

I have an excel with some data. Say:

- Column A has data till Row 3;
- Column B has data till Row 18;
- Column C has data till Row 12;

I need a method with arguments column and data, that goes to the next available cell in that column and enters the data.

For example appendData(0,"Xyz") should enter "Xyz" in cell A4.
I am using jxl. Here is what I could get till now..

```
    public static void appendData(int column, String data) throws BiffException, IOException, WriteException{
    Workbook file=Workbook.getWorkbook(inputWorkbook);
    WritableWorkbook writeBook=Workbook.createWorkbook(inputWorkbook,file);
    WritableSheet sheet = writeBook.getSheet(0);
    WritableFont wf=new WritableFont(WritableFont.ARIAL);

    WritableCellFormat cf = new WritableCellFormat(wf);

    cf.setWrap(true);
    for (int i = 0; i <= sheet.getRows(); i++) {
        Cell cell = sheet.getCell(column, i);
        String cellContent = cell.getContents().toString();
        if (cellContent.isEmpty()) {
            Label label = new Label(column, i, data,cf);
            sheet.addCell(label);
        }
    }
    writeBook.write();
    writeBook.close();
    return;
}

    public static void main(String[] args) throws BiffException, WriteException, IOException{
    appendData(0, "UID1");
```

}

It is failing with following error:

Exception in thread "main" jxl.write.biff.RowsExceededException: The maximum number of rows permitted on a worksheet been exceeded
    at jxl.write.biff.WritableSheetImpl.getRowRecord(WritableSheetImpl.java:1214)
    at jxl.write.biff.WritableSheetImpl.addCell(WritableSheetImpl.java:1151)
    at com.tivo.tsg.common.XLWriter.appendData(XLWriter.java:59)
    at com.tivo.tsg.common.XLWriter.main(XLWriter.java:79)

Can Somebody please help?

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: PS: I have checked similar questions related to JXL. Couldn't get enough info on my scenario.

Comment: Is it as simple as changing `i <=` to just `i <` ?

Comment: Q: What are the #/rows when you hit the error.  Q: Have you looked at [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13658369/java-jxl-exception-with-maximum-row) or [this one](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaExcel/article.html)?  Q: What's with "i <= sheet.getRows()"?  Is that intentional, or a bug?

Comment: @DMoses: That didn't work...! I want to enter data into the cell that is immediately available(isEmpty) in that column..

Comment: @paulsm4: with "i<=sheet.getRows()" - I am trying to get the used rows in that column and the row after that in that column must be empty and my data should go into that cell...  I did look at the examples, but didn;t help much..

Comment: are you writing on a row that exceeds the max?  Because that's what the exception is telling you.

Comment: ??? so what does "i" equal when the problem occurs ???  3?  18?  12? 65537?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void appendData(int column, String data) throws BiffException, IOException, WriteException{
    Workbook file=Workbook.getWorkbook(inputWorkbook);
    WritableWorkbook writeBook=Workbook.createWorkbook(inputWorkbook,file);
    WritableSheet sheet = writeBook.getSheet(0);
    WritableFont wf=new WritableFont(WritableFont.ARIAL);
    WritableCellFormat cf = new WritableCellFormat(wf);
    cf.setWrap(true);
    Cell[] cell = sheet.getColumn(column);
    int len = cell.length;
    Label label = new Label(column, len, data,cf);
    sheet.addCell(label);
    writeBook.write();
    writeBook.close();
    return;
}
```

This worked for me! I guess my previous approach itself was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** Old version of Microsoft Excel (file extension  is *.xls) supports 65536 (2 power 16). Check whether you are trying to get or write somewhere greater than 65536 rows.

**Troubleshoot options:**

1. Print the value of 'i' inside the loop and see at what count it fails. It may give some more clue.
2. What is like 59 in your file. The exception starts at line 59 in your code. share the details and it can help. 
   com.tivo.tsg.common.XLWriter.appendData(XLWriter.java:59)
3. Check the last 2 answers from this link which suggests to set additional options. It may help to resolve the problem.

   http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/518045/maximum-number-rows-within-excel-spreadsheet